# LORA IOT AES-128 decryption

Tags: java, node.js, aes, iot, lora

I would like to ask you, have you ever coded AES-128 encrypt or decrypt for LORA IOT sensor with javascript or node js?
I have a payload (encrypted) and kay value pair in HEX. Could you help me which method shoud I use to the payload to I got the original payload?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using LoRa or LoRaWAN?

I think you are probably using LoRaWAN. If so you could check [TTN's github](https://github.com/TheThingsNetwork/lora_gateway) as reference or just use TTN as your gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Since the data is encrypted, suppose that you are using LoRaWAN.

First of all, we should know which type of the packet is. Is it an uplink message or a downlink message? You may refer to the [LoRaWAN specification](https://www.lora-alliance.org/portals/0/specs/LoRaWAN%20Specification%201R0.pdf) to figure out the message type.

Secondly, you may move ahead to understand how MAC frame payload is encrypted/decrypted. The section.4 in the specification can help you.

Thirdly, if you want to implement the encryption/decryption in , maybe this pure node.js repo can help you: [anthonykirby/lora-packet](https://github.com/anthonykirby/lora-packet). Please pay attention to the LoRaWAN packet structure, there payload(data) is only part of the whole packet. You may filter the data first, and then do decryption. Hope this could solve your problem.